# SQL Get all filtered items

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, filter

I have problem with fetching data from table where every item have to match filter requirements from another table where exists relations between product_id, feature_category_id and feature_option_id.

Eg. Here is example inserts from that helper table:

```
id = 1
product_id = 10
feature_category_id = 100 - it's name of "feature category" eg. dimensions, weight etc.
feature_option_id = 1001 - it's product value of feature category eg. this product with id 10 have dimensions of 100x100 and it's id in another table is 1001 so it's that value.
```

Now I need to get all products which match these feature options requirements. Eg. I choose from search form give me all products with dimensions 100x100 and weight 1kg, so query should do something to check this data in table.

I tried something but it only work if there is 1 product.features.feature_category_id. If where is 2 or more where clauses of that type there is 0 returned rows.

```
select distinct 
    "products".*, "product_categories.*"
from 
    "products" 
inner join 
    "product_categories" on "products"."category_id" = "product_categories"."id" 
left join 
    "product_features" on "products"."id" = "product_features"."product_id" 
where 
    "products"."category_id" in (58) and 
    ((product_features.feature_category_id = 1 
      and product_features.feature_option_id = 58) 
     and (product_features.feature_category_id = 46 
          and product_features.feature_option_id = 62))
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the products that match your conditions using `group by` and `having`:

```
select p.id
from products p join
     product_categories pc
     on p.category_id = pc."id" left join
     product_features pf
     on p.id = pf.product_id
where p.category_id in (58) and 
      ((pf.feature_category_id = 1 and pf.feature_option_id = 58) or 
       (pf.feature_category_id = 46 and pf.feature_option_id = 62)
      )
group by p.id
having count(distinct feature_category_id) = 2;
```

If you need more fields from the `select`, you can either join them in or include them in the `group by`.

Comment: That should help just to figure how to do that in Laravel because having method in his DB query builder is not able to take that form of data?